# Finding path between two Locations Feasible design

Tags: algorithm, system-design

In my application i have lane defined across multiple geo hierarchy (Location,zip,city-state,state,country) between origin and destination.
O in prefix stands for Origin
D in prefix stands for Destination
For eg: Following can be lane configuration stored in db.

[image: Lane Configuration in DB]

If i search from Any Location in city Hutchins apart from UP - Dallas Intermodal Terminal (DIT) as origin to any location in city San Pedro .I should
be able to get following lanes as output.
Outputs:

```
1. Lane1 -> Lane2  -> Lane3
2. Lane5 -> Lane3 
3. Lane4
```

If i search from UP - Dallas Intermodal Terminal (DIT) as origin to any location in city San Pedro .I should be able to get following lanes as output.
Outputs:

```
1. Lane2 -> Lane3
2. Lane4
```

Now i am using JGraphT to build the graph but i have following problems

1.Since by origin and destination can be across multiple geo hierarchy what should be the node.

2.Entry point for graph as origin destination supplied might changes.

I can have 100 thousand lanes stored in Db across mulitple geo hierarchy.
Also would like this graph to be build before hand instead of building when request comes.
Please provide how to approach this problem in efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

1. It is not a problem. Just gather data to a dictionary or a class and pass it as node. Or just enumerate each node, construct graph with this numeration, and when you will need to get node number, just get it from its separeted storage. This is a good approach, especially when you use some DB. You can just access it by node index.
2. You don't want to have ALL paths. As you mentioned you have 100 thousand rows. It will be a **very** large amout of combinations. Instead of that, I suggest to get only the shortest paths. For that you can use [this](https://python-jgrapht.readthedocs.io/en/jgrapht-1.5.0.3/api/algorithms/shortestpaths.html#algorithms). As you can see, there is no problem to specify origin and destination.

Comment: Thanks for you response.Real issue is how would i query for connected rows.Since there can be n number of rows.And i cant hit database n number of time.Any insight on this would be useful.